# Connect Loginuser Control in asp.net to remote SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, login-control

Loginuser Control runner perfectly well on local host but I need to put it online and connect it to my SQL Data base. I am clueless as to how to do it and how the requisite table will be created in my remote SQL Data base.

Comment: LoginUser is used to connect to same computer and not remote computer.  If its just for connecting to remote SQL Server, just specify that in the connection string (the uid and password). Can you please elaborate what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to create a login module for my website. I want to use this control to take care of new user creation and password without me doing coding for all forms.

Comment: You meant that you want to add new user to the Domain?